# VS Code Extensions suddenly crash

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was styling nested modal elements on a working styles.scss file and suddenly my extensions Live Sass Compiler and Live Server crushed. Every time i open my project Extensions host terminated unexpectedly and it purposes me open developer tools or restart extension host. What should i do in order to make it work again?

[image: img1]

Comment: Report such issues to the extension authors please (unless you are confident that you can debug the root cause).

Answer (score 0):

Today i opened the project and everything worked fine. Probably it was caused from an update of VSCode or live Sass Compiler conflicted with node-sass. I disabled temporally live Sass Compiler and i git reset to previous commit.